# Delegate of UIScrollView / Subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, delegates, uiscrollview

can you help me setting up a delegate for a UIScrollView, so I can interact with it from within it's subviews?

Following problem:

I added some UIViewControllers (with extra nibs) to a UIScrollView. I want to control the ScrollView from within those subviews. E.g. I want to disable scrolling when I press a button.

In another thread I read, that this can be done using delegates. I tried that based on a tutorial, but no chance... The controller structure is following:

```
BlaViewController
{
-- UIScrollView
---- UIView (View1Controller) --> Including the button which should control the UIScrollView
---- UIView (View2Controller)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your code, let's see what you've tried.

Comment: actually i removed it, but i will reconstruct it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you guessed using delegates in correct. My guess is you're just not implementing it correctly. Have a look at [Stanford iPhone Dev](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewiTunesUCollection?id=384233222) the 11th lecture to how to do it.